# Why does pdflatex crash on \includegraphics?

Tags: graphics, pdftex

This piece of code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{a}
b
\includegraphics{Nomogram3d_v05a.pdf}
c

\end{document}
```

Crashes `pdflatex` with the following error message:

```
Command Line:   pdflatex.exe --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 "tst.tex"
Startup Folder: D:\klad

This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (MiKTeX 2.9)
entering extended mode
(D:\klad\tst.tex
LaTeX2e <2011/06/27>
Babel <v3.8m> and hyphenation patterns for english, afrikaans, ancientgreek, ar
abic, armenian, assamese, basque, bengali, bokmal, bulgarian, catalan, coptic,
croatian, czech, danish, dutch, esperanto, estonian, farsi, finnish, french, ga
lician, german, german-x-2013-05-26, greek, gujarati, hindi, hungarian, iceland
ic, indonesian, interlingua, irish, italian, kannada, kurmanji, latin, latvian,
 lithuanian, malayalam, marathi, mongolian, mongolianlmc, monogreek, ngerman, n
german-x-2013-05-26, nynorsk, oriya, panjabi, pinyin, polish, portuguese, roman
ian, russian, sanskrit, serbian, slovak, slovenian, spanish, swedish, swissgerm
an, tamil, telugu, turkish, turkmen, ukenglish, ukrainian, uppersorbian, usengl
ishmax, welsh, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size12.clo"))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\pdftex-def\pdftex.def"
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\infwarerr.sty")
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\generic\oberdiek\ltxcmds.sty"))))
No file tst.aux.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\context\base\supp-pdf.mkii"
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)Syntax Error: Kid object (page 1) is not an indirect reference (dictionary)
```

If I comment out the `\includegraphics` statement, i.e. if I run:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\section{a}
b
c

\end{document}
```

Everything works and produces output. I checked that the file `Nomogram3d_v05a.pdf` exists and renders without problems in Sumatrapdf viewer.

Comment: And yes, before anyone asks, the include file is in the same directory as the .tex file.

Comment: Try with some other graphic.

Comment: Did that, same result. In fact this nomogram graphic is the fourth .pdf graphic I tries. All crashed with the exact same error message. If you can point me to a guaranteed "proper" pdf file on the web I'm happy to try that.

Comment: Try with one of the graphics of the mwe-package, e.g. `example-image.pdf`

Comment: Try running in demo mode: \usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

Comment: Also try renaming the pdf to remove the underscore.

Comment: @Ulrike Including the graphics file example-image.pdf  worked. So it's something in those .pdf files (and fragility of pdflatex).

Comment: is it a single page pdf file?

Comment: I vaguely recall something like this happening when the pdf file contained vector graphics with weird coordinates....  like NaN.

Comment: @Aubrey: (1) Removing the underscore did nothing. (2) Loading the package with the [demo] option allowed pdftex to run to completion but now I get a black square where the graphic should be.

Comment: @Jpi. Yes. One smallish image (about 5x6 cm). I got the first .pdf graph that failed from the Scribus package. I thought it produced clean .pdf files.

Comment: Then it might be an idea to post the PDF somewhere so others can test it. There might be something odd in it. I've never seen that error before.

Comment: Any suggestions where? I'm not very knowledgeable about where to drop off files.

Comment: Best not to include the extension (but that is not a suggested solution - just a 'by the way' - as it won't cause this sort of problem).

Comment: I encountered this error after creating a pdf in R but not correctly closing the device using `dev.off()`.

Answer (score 6):

I do not see a reason not to believe the error message, that the included PDF file is invalid. The application that has created the PDF file is buggy. Try

```
pdfinfo Nomogram3d_v05a.pdf
```

to get a hint, which program might be the culprit.

### Description of the error

Pages are organized as page tree with a pages object as root, intermediate nodes and leaves, the pages. All these objects must be numbered objects (aka indirect object), because some PDF features references page dictionary objects. If this object is directly embedded in the page tree, then it does not have a number.

### How to reproduce

I created such a faulty PDF file. Inside `/Kids [...]` there should be an indirect reference `2 0 obj`, which contains the contents `<</Type/Page...>>`.
In this case, the latter object is directly put into the `/Kids` array making the PDF file invalid.

```pdf
%PDF-1.5
%ÐÔÅØ
3 0 obj
<<
/Length 37
>>
stream
1 0 0 1 40 40 cm
0 0 20 20 re f
endstream
endobj
1 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [ /PDF ]
>>
endobj
4 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
/Kids [
  <<
    /Type/Page
    /Contents 3 0 R
    /Resources 1 0 R
    /Parent 4 0 R
    /MediaBox[0 0 100 100]
  >>
]
>>
endobj
5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 4 0 R
>>
endobj
xref
0 6
0000000002 65535 f
0000000096 00000 n
0000000000 00000 f
0000000015 00000 n
0000000135 00000 n
0000000299 00000 n
trailer
<< /Size 6
/Root 5 0 R
>>
startxref
348
%%EOF
```

Hint: The lines ending with `f` or `n` after `xref` must either end with DOS line ends (`"\r\n"` = bytes 13 and 10) or end with a space and new line (`"␣\n"` = bytes 32 and 10).

### Results with some PDF programs

- MiKTeX's pdfTeX 1.40.16, MiKTeX's `pdfinfo` 0.32.0, TeX Live's `pdfinfo` 0.30.0 show the error:

  ```
  Syntax Error: Kid object (page 1) is not an indirect reference (dictionary)
  ```
- SumatraPDF v3.0 displays the document.
- Adobe Acrobat Reader DC 2015 displays the document, but cannot save it because of an unspecified reading error.
- `pdftk` 2.02 breaks with:

  ```
  Unhandled Java Exception in create_output():
  ExceptionConverter: java.io.IOException: The document has no pages.
  ```
- TeX Live's pdfTeX 1.40.16 and `xpdf` 3.03 break with:

  ```
  Syntax Error: Page tree reference is wrong type (dictionary)
  Syntax Error: Invalid page count in page tree
  ```
- Ghostscript's `ps2pdf` 9.15 and 9.16 work.

### Repair of the PDF file

For the repair a program is needed, which is tolerant enough to read and understand the file and corrects the error, when the file is saved.

- (-) Saving the file via SumatraPDF just copies the file, but does not repair it.
- (-) AR or `pdftk` fail to read and/or save the file.
- (+) Ghostscript succeeds:

  ```
  ps2pdf Nomogram3d_v05a.pdf Nomogram3d_v05a-fixed.pdf
  ```

Comment: *I do not see a reason not to believe the error message, that the included PDF file is invalid.* I'm confused by this. The OP describes this as a "crash," and the output does not have an error message in it.

Comment: @BenCrowell See the last line of the console output.

Comment: Oops, now I see it. The final line was hidden in my browser, and I needed to scroll down to see it.

Comment: @Heiko: pdfinfo came up with the same error info but the pdf file didn't contain any further information. I know what software produced them though. I was able to correct some of my .pdf files by updating Scribus (from 1.4.0 to 1.4.5) and I'm working on the rest. Perhaps a suggestion to the writers of pdflatex: the error message gave me no clue that it was complaining about a .pdf file and not e.g. the latex file or some intermediary file. If possible the error message should tell where (in what file) it found something amiss.

Comment: @latexconfused I think, the error message and abortion was issued by the library, which is used by pdfTeX to include the PDF file. Thus, it might not be in the full control of pdfTeX.